# Client hangs when passing cookies between DefaultHttpClients

Tags: java, android, cookies, client-server

I have a strange problem I have been trying to solve for the last two days, and seem to have narrowed it down to the cookies attached to the global `DefaultHttpClient` variable associated with my application.

When I use the client with post params, everything hangs after the first time it is used. I don't get any requests to my server, the application just refuses to do anything. If there are no post parameters, everything works just fine. Here is the applicable code.

```
httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(pairs,"UTF-8"));
DefaultHttpClient defhttpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
logger.info("URL Encoded");
//When I pass the cookies things stop working...
//defhttpClient.setCookieStore(httpclient.get_cookies());
response = defhttpClient.execute(httppost);
logger.info("Received response");
```

If I make a new `DefaultHttpClient` and run the post request with parameters, the client can talk to the server just fine. The only problem is that I need the cookies from the old client to tell the server who the current user is. When I take the cookies from my old client and give them to my new one, the application hangs. Again, I dont even see a request coming into my server.

Does anyone have any idea what's going on here?

Answer (score 0):

Alright, so I couldn't figure out how to do this by sending the message in the body with setentity. Just decided to put the json data in the header instead and everything seems to work fine. Not really too big of a problem. Would have preferred to do it the right way, but sometimes you can't get everything you want. Here is the code for anyone with the same problem.

```
JSONObject post_params = new JSONObject();
for(NameValuePair pair : pairs){
    post_params.put(pair.getName(), pair.getValue());
} 
httppost.setHeader("json",post_params.toString());
response = httpclient.get_client().execute(httppost);
```